# GDB tracing: Target returns error code '01' after continue command

Tags: gdb, trace, gdbserver

I am trying to obtain GDB traces as described in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345958/gdb-tracing-no-current-trace-frame).
For completeness, on one terminal I am running:

```
$ gdbserver :1234 ./a.out 
Process ./a.out created; pid = 13610
Listening on port 1234
```

And on another one (client):

```
$ gdb ./a.out
...
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.2
Reading symbols from ./a.out...
(gdb) target remote :1234
Remote debugging using :1234
Reading /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 from remote target...
warning: File transfers from remote targets can be slow. Use "set sysroot" to access files locally instead.
Reading /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 from remote target...
Reading symbols from target:/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/45/87364908de169dec62ffa538170118c1c3a078.debug...
0x00007ffff7fd0100 in _start () from target:/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) trace 3
Tracepoint 1 at 0x555555555157: file ../test/main.cpp, line 3.
(gdb)  b 9
Breakpoint 2 at 0x55555555519a: file ../test/main.cpp, line 9.
(gdb) actions 1
Enter actions for tracepoint 1, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".
>collect $regs,$args
>end
(gdb) tstart
(gdb) c
```

And here is where it differs from the other question, I get the error when I want to continue to the breakpoint at 9:

```
Continuing.
Reading /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 from remote target...
Target returns error code '01'.
```

I tried the whole experiment *without* the tracepoint, and the continue command works correctly.

Of course I tried googling the error code 01, but seems pretty generic so I could not draw any conclusions. Any idea what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a [known issue](https://review.lttng.org/c/binutils-gdb/+/9084), apparently tracepoints have been broken since binutils 2.33 and a patch was added to fix them in 2.41.

Your GDB/binutils version must be some inbetween. Here are the two commits:

- Broken since binutils-2_33 (07/2019) : [cb1e4e32c2d9588e1d77ea49bafb5dcdc1cff764](https://github.com/bminor/binutils-gdb/commit/cb1e4e32c2d9588e1d77ea49bafb5dcdc1cff764)
- Fixed from binutils-2_41 (03/2023) :
  [0b63c811efc38f50b72422ed6a9db1de053e8736](https://github.com/bminor/binutils-gdb/commit/0b63c811efc38f50b72422ed6a9db1de053e8736)

Try again with version 2.41 or later.

Comment: This is the answer, I had to build the latest GDB myself, the one that came with the system was:
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.2
The one I built:
GNU gdb (GDB) 14.0.50.20230730-git
Now it works. thanks!

Comment: Just beware of the comment in the issue description:
> "Things remain quite broken in that area though." Meaning tracepoints support in GDB seems to be unmaintained and probably not fully functional.